# Polish transversals

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, measure-theory, axiom-of-choice, continuum-theory

A subset of $X$ an indecomposable continuum $Y$ is called a *composant transversal* if $X$ has exactly one point from each composant of $Y$.

So a continuum has a composant transversal precisely when there exists a choice function on its set of composants.

Solecki proved that no indecomposable continuum has a Borel composant transversal.

*Solecki, Sławomir*, [**The space of composants of an indecomposable continuum**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/aima.2001.2002), Adv. Math. 166, No. 2, 149-192 (2002). [ZBL1014.54021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1014.54021).

But what if we ask something a little different:

**Main Question.**  Let $X$ be a dense Polish subspace of an indecomposable continuum $Y$.  Must some composant of $Y$ contain at least two points of $X$?

If "Borel" replaces "Polish", then I have an example showing the answer is no. But I suspect the answer is yes.  For instance, it is not difficult to show that a dense $G_\delta$-subset of $C\times[0,1]$ must contain uncountably many points from each of  uncountably many arcs $\{c\}\times[0,1]$.

*Ideas:* If the union of all composants touching $X$ is Polish, then I think Solecki's results show the answer is yes.  But the most I can show is that $X$ is a countable union of $G_\delta$-sets.  Another idea is to suppose $X$ is a Polish "partial transversal", and then show $X$ can be extended to a Borel composant transversal, reaching a contradiction.

---

On another note, by Solecki's result the existence of composant transversals seems to require something close to the full-blown axiom of choice, or at least  AC$(\mathbb R)$.

**Other questions.**

- Are composant transversals non-measurable?
- Does something like ZF$+$AD$+$DC imply there is no composant transversal?

Comment: Each Polish space contains a dense zero-dimensional Polish subspace (this follows from the Lavretiev Theorem). For this dense zero-dimensional subspace the composants are singletons.